# How to remove duplication of following async Typescript function?

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, e2e-testing

I wrote e2e test using Typescript but `beforeEach` method content using four places. It given sonar issues as duplication content. I need to extract that method to separate function and called in each `beforeEach` method (=> place given sonar duplicate issue).

```
describe('Acomment', () => {

 let a: A;
 beforeEach(async () => {
    a= new A();   //duplicatie
    await a.navigateToPage(); //duplicatie
    await a.scanPatient('aaa'); //duplicatie
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const navigateToAAndScanPatient = async () => {
  const a = new A();   
  await a.navigateToPage(); 
  await a.scanPatient('aaa');
  return a
}

describe('Acomment', () => {
 let a: A
 beforeEach(async () => {
   a = await navigateToAAndScanPatient()
  })
})
```